# Problem installing Flash player standlone version in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, adobe-flash

Recently I tried to install Adobe Flash Player Standalone version on Archlinux using AUR packages.There was no Tarball to download and i cloned the git repo.When i ran makepkg it gives me a error.

> ERROR: One or more files did not pass the validity check!"

How to fix this ? [image]
Thanks !
Srivin Prabhash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means that (for whatever reason) the checksums used to verify the source files (see [Integrity](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#Integrity) on the Arch wiki) in the PKGBUILD are not matching the checksums produced by running `sha512sum` on the file makepkg downloaded. This could mean that someone has managed to make your computer download a different file than the person who created the PKGBUILD (for example by replacing the file on Adobes servers, messing with the connection between your computer and Adobes servers, ...).

But since the URL for the tarball is not for a specific version of the Flash player and adobe has released a new version (11.2.202.616) for Linux, the problem is just that the checksums need to be updated for the new tarball. You can do that by running `updpkgsums` in the directory containing the PKGBUILD file. Usually the provider of the tarball would provide checksums himself that you can use to verify `updpkgsums` downloaded the correct file or to manually edit them in the PKGBUILD, but Adobe doesn't seem to do that.

FWIW, after running `updpkgsums` the `sha512sums` array looks like this on my computer:

```
sha512sums=('518b3dd494af2b10404b6039385ad304e6273f6bad3e57e5f77710c810f3e29c8220920ea221c1e9012a2e795fd0da4db7d419946ce8db1db19ccaa744e9ca46'
            'a70fd7127f0f9d64f2c872d1e4634d93e24fdea165abfbe20724e68c1b7297df46362cb449b5a78d0eb4a68e43426965359ca93fd4ba4848d2542e5505bcd2fe'
            'e4139b265896ebd276b4c7931d5718db7ac8b25e5e86decb2161c94d2b6b410dc7160667cda3a330ece40e64e7809d7afc5ddcc94e09352e84359fa4c7fe3e2d')
```

If you know a PKGBUILD on the AUR needs to be updated for a new version of the package, make sure to also click "Flag package out-of-date" to notify the maintainer. I've done that for this package already.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly and i installed Flash Player. Thanks for the Answer. and Thanks for you advise on outdated PKGBUILD :) Thumbs up

Comment: It's great that my answer helped you! Here at Unix.SE you can mark answers that answered your question as [accepted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), it would be great if you could do that.

Comment: Ah sorry for the late action .. And im done :)